# How to exclude prime numbers from a sequence finding function?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write code that takes a list of integers and finds the longest declining sublist and writes down the length and sum of it. However, prime numbers are not included into the sublists and if two sublists are of same length then the program choses the one of a larger sum.

So far I have written this but I don't see how I can include the prime number rule into it. I am new to programming.

```
print("input:")

# input creates a list of numbers divided by a space
n = list(map(int, input().split()))


def prime(x):  # False if x is not a prime number, True if x is a prime number
    for i in range(2, x):
        if abs(x) % i == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True


def longest_decreasing_sequence(n):

    # lds[] is longest list of decreasing numbers; current[] is the current list of decreasing numbers in the cycle
    lds, current = [], [n[0]]
    for val in n[1:]:  # takes values from the list from item 1 to input list end
        if val < current[-1]:  # decreasing test
            current.append(val)  # add it to lds[] list

        else:
            if len(current) > len(lds):  # update lds[] if current[] has more items
                lds = current[:]

            elif len(current) == len(lds):  # if current[] has equal items compare sums
                if sum(current) > sum(lds):  # if sum of current[] > sum of lds[]
                    lds = current[:]  # update lds[] list

            else:
                lds
            # sets current to value where decreasing sequence test failed
            current = [val]

    if len(current) > len(lds):  # if current[] has more items, update lds[]
        lds = current[:]

    else:
        lds
    return lds


print("lds:", longest_decreasing_sequence(n))
print("length:", len(longest_decreasing_sequence(n)))
print("sum:", sum(longest_decreasing_sequence(n)))
```

end of code.

```
example 1:
input:
5 -4 -8 7 -10
output: #[-4 -8] is the longest declining sublist
2 #length
-12 #sum

example 2:
input:
23 -4 -6 -10 0 1 3 6 4 0 5 5 10
output: #sum[6 4 0] > sum [-4 -6 -10]
3
10

example 3:
input:
2 7 3 5 11
output:
0
0
```

Comment: Hint: You only want to append val if it is not prime

Comment: yes, however I don’t know how to include the condition to work even for n[0] because only values from n[1:] are appended.